# Don't understand the logic behind the problem

Tags: java, methods, boolean

i'm trying to understand what the problem with my code is.
Here is the task and my code:

Write a method named canPack with three parameters of type int named bigCount, smallCount, and goal.

- The parameter bigCount represents the count of big flour bags (5 kilos each).
- The parameter smallCount represents the count of small flour bags (1 kilo each).
- The parameter goal represents the goal amount of kilos of flour needed to assemble a package.

Therefore, the sum of the kilos of bigCount and smallCount must be at least equal to the value of goal. The method should return true if it is possible to make a package with goal kilos of flour.

If the sum is greater than goal, ensure that only full bags are used towards the goal amount. For example, if goal = 9, bigCount = 2, and smallCount = 0, the method should return false since each big bag is 5 kilos and cannot be divided. However, if goal = 9, bigCount = 1, and smallCount = 5, the method should return true because of 1 full bigCount bag and 4 full smallCount bags equal goal, and it's okay if there are additional bags left over.

If any of the parameters are negative, return false.

EXAMPLE INPUT/OUTPUT:

- canPack (1, 0, 4); should return false since bigCount is 1 (big bag of 5 kilos) and goal is 4 kilos.
- canPack (1, 0, 5); should return true since bigCount is 1 (big bag of 5 kilos) and goal is 5 kilos.
- canPack (0, 5, 4); should return true since smallCount is 5 (small bags of 1 kilo) and goal is 4 kilos, and we have 1 bag left which is ok as mentioned above.
- canPack (2, 2, 11); should return true since bigCount is 2 (big bags 5 kilos each) and smallCount is 2 (small bags of 1 kilo), makes in total 12 kilos and goal is 11 kilos.
- canPack (-3, 2, 12); should return false since bigCount is negative.

```
    public static boolean canPack(int bigCount, int smallCount, int goal) {
        
        int bigCountKilos = bigCount * 5;
        int smallCountKilos = smallCount;
        
        if (bigCount < 0 || smallCount < 0 || goal < 0) {
            return false;
        } else {
            
            if (bigCountKilos >= goal && bigCountKilos % goal == 0) {
                return true;
            } else if (bigCountKilos + smallCountKilos >= goal && bigCountKilos % goal == 0) {
                return true;
            } else if (bigCountKilos < goal && bigCountKilos + smallCountKilos >= goal) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(canPack(4, 18, 19));
    }
```

The instance for 4,18,19 should return true but it doesn't. Could someone tell me what i'm doing wrong?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please explaing the reasoning for `bigCountKilos + smallCountKilos >= goal && bigCountKilos % goal == 0`

Comment: Also, kindly asking: is this somesort of assignment? Also also, think about the case `goal = 20, big = 4, small = 3`

Comment: Sorrty ment `goal = 19, big = 4, small = 3`

Comment: Please do not completely rewrite questions. This invalidates answers and is not allowed on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

```
int bigCountKilo = bigCount*5;
    if(bigCountKilo+smallCount*1 == goal){
        return true;
    }else if((bigCountKilo>=goal&&bigCountKilo%goal == 0)||(bigCountKilo>=goal&&goal%5<=smallCount)){
        return true;
    }else if(smallCount>=goal){
        return true;
    }else if(bigCountKilo+smallCount>goal&&goal%bigCountKilo<=smallCount){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

This will work for all the conditions. Please try this and if anything wrong Kindly update.

Answer (score 1):

This code works on the greedy algorithm and passes all the test cases, give it a try:

```java
public static boolean canPack(int bigCount, int smallCount, int goal) {
    // Here we are checking if the inputs are valid
    if (bigCount < 0 || smallCount < 0 || goal < 0 || (bigCount*5 + smallCount)  < goal) {
        return false;
    }

    // Here we multiply bigCount with 5 since each bigCount contains 5 kg
    int bigCountKilo = bigCount * 5;

    // We check if goal > 5 and then subtract bigCount from it till the goal is less than 5kg
    while (goal >= 5) {
        if (bigCountKilo > 0) {
            goal -= 5;
            bigCount-=1;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    // Similarly here too we are checking if goal is greater than 0 and then subtracting smallCount values
    while (goal > 0) {
        if (smallCount > 0) {
            goal -= 1;
            smallCount -= 1;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    // We are returning true if goal is reached (if goal becomes zero)
    return (goal == 0);
}
```

Comment: You can use `code block` for `code section` that will make question/answer more readable and good. For more info you check this [link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#184109)

Answer (score 1):

Hey the explanation is pretty simple
I hope you have understood the upper part until the bigCount, smallCount and goal.

So let's begin...
let's assume goal = 9kg. It means you have to make a package that contains 9kg of flour.
Now bigCount= 2(means 10kg) and smallCount = 0.

How much flour you have (bigCount*5) + smallCount = 10kg
do you have enough flour to make a package? Yes.
Can you make a package of 9kg? No.
Because you have two  bags of 5kg each and you cannot take 1kg out from any bag.

Consider second scenario
let's assume goal = 9kg. It means you have to make a package that contains 9kg of flour.
Now bigCount= 1(means 5kg) and smallCount = 5(means 5kg).

Now you still have 10kg of flour but the question is can you make a package without taking any flour from any bag? this time Yes.

5kg + 1kg + 1kg + 1kg +1kg = 9kg and 1kg extra.

Simply telling you can have extra flour but you cannot take flour from bags just to reach the goal.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like your logic behind finding the answer is not correct. The `if` statements don't cover all the cases and don't produce the right answer every time.

A basic approach would be something like:

- Subtract 5 from goal, and subtract 1 from bigCount while goal > 0 and bigCount > 0
- If goal is still > 0, check if smallCount >= goal. If yes, return true, else false.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static boolean canPack(
    final int bigCount,
    final int smallCount,
    final int goal
) {

    // return goal - Math.min(goal / 5, bigCount) * 5 <= smallCount;

    final int numberOfBigNeeded = goal / 5;
    final int numberOfBigUsed = Math.min(numberOfBigNeeded, bigCount);
    final int remainingKilosFromGoalAfterUsingBig = goal - numberOfBigUsed * 5;
    final boolean hasEnoughSmallToCoverRemainingKilosFromGoalAfterUsingBig = remainingKilosFromGoalAfterUsingBig <= smallCount;
    return hasEnoughSmallToCoverRemainingKilosFromGoalAfterUsingBig;
}
```

Comment: You need to explain your answer in order to ensure that the asker will understand this.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static boolean canPack(int bigCount, int smallCount, int goal) {
    // Input validation.
    if (bigCount < 0 || smallCount < 0 || goal < 0) {
        return false;
    }
    // Create a variable for the the bigCount variable to show it in kg.
    int bigCountInKg = bigCount * 5;
    
    if (bigCountInKg < goal) {
        int result = goal - bigCountInKg;
        if (result <= smallCount) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else if (bigCountInKg == goal) {
        return true;
    } else if (bigCountInKg > goal) {
        int maxBigCount = goal / 5;
        int result = goal - maxBigCount;
        if (result <= smallCount) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: While this code block may answer the question, it would be best if you could provide a little explanation for why it does so.

Answer (score 0):

public static boolean canpack(int bigcount,int smallcount,int goal) {

```
    if(bigcount<0||smallcount<0||goal<0) {
        return false;
    }
    int a=bigcount*5;
    int b=smallcount*1;
    if(a+b>goal&&a<goal) {
        return true;
    }else if(a+b==goal) {
        return true;
    }else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Hope it works.If not kindly inform me.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to provide more information as to how the code you've provided works. Code-only answers might solve the problem of the original asker but they don't help future readers understand the solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution for Flour packer issue

```java
public class FlourPacker {

    public static boolean canPack(int bigCount, int smallCount, int goal) {
        boolean  bool=false;
        int bigCountKilos = bigCount * 5;
    
        if(bigCount == 0 && smallCount>=goal) {
             bool= true;
        } else if(smallCount==0 && bigCountKilos>= goal && goal%bigCountKilos==0) {
            bool= true;
        } else if (bigCount > 0 && smallCount>0 && goal >= 0) {
            int bigCountTotal= bigCount*5;
            int total=bigCountTotal+smallCount;
            if(total==goal){
                 bool= true;
            }
            
            if(goal/5<bigCount && goal%5 <=smallCount){
                bool= true;
            }
            
            if(bigCountTotal<=goal && goal-bigCountTotal <=smallCount) {
                bool= true;
            }
        }
        
        return bool;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```java
public static boolean canPack(int bigCount, int smallCount, int goal) {
    if ((bigCount < 0) || (smallCount < 0) || (goal < 0)) {
      return false;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i <= bigCount; i++){
      for (int j = 0; j <= smallCount; j++) {
        if (i*5 + j == goal){
          return true;
        }
      }
    }
    return false;
        
  }
```

I used nested loop to iterate all possible way to reach the goal. But I found another solution online which is much simpler so I would like to share with you guys too.
credit to Vincent's corner.

```java
public class FlourPacker {
    public static boolean canPack(int bigCount, int smallCount, int goal) {

        if (bigCount < 0 || smallCount < 0 || goal < 0) {
            return false;
        }

        if (bigCount * 5 > goal) {
            return smallCount >= goal % 5;
        }

        return smallCount >= goal - (bigCount * 5);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution without loops, and which is simpler to understand.

```
public static boolean canPack(int bigCount , int smallCount , int goal) {
    if (bigCount < 0 || smallCount < 0 || goal < 0 || ((bigCount * 5 + smallCount) < goal)) {
        return false;
     }

    if (bigCount * 5 == goal) return true;
    int maxBigCount = (int) goal / 5; // max bigcount required in goal

    int requiredBigCount = (maxBigCount <= bigCount) ? maxBigCount : bigCount; // the amount of bigCount fit into the goal
    
    return (requiredBigCount * 5) + smallCount >= goal; // the fited kg can be equal or higher than the goal
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Without using nested loops, we first ensure the bigCount can fit into the goal size. We run a while loop to test this. Everytime the bigCount fits into the goal size, we increment the count and decrement the goal size, When the bigCount cannot fit into the goal size without spilling over we break. Then we start adding the small counts until the goal is reached or the small size depletes, whichever comes first.

```java
public class FlourPacker {

    public static boolean canPack(int bigCount, int smallCount, int goal) {

        int sizeOfBigCount = 5 * bigCount;
        int sizeOfSmallCount = 1 * smallCount;
        int totalCount = 0;
        int goalControl = goal;

        if (totalCount < goal) {
            while (sizeOfBigCount > 0) {
                if ((totalCount + 5) <= goalControl) {
                    totalCount += 5;
                    goal -= 5;
                }

                sizeOfBigCount -= 5;

                if ((totalCount + 5) > goalControl) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if (totalCount < goalControl) {
            while (sizeOfSmallCount > 0) {
                if ((totalCount + 1) <= goalControl) {
                    totalCount++;
                    goal--;
                }

                sizeOfSmallCount--;

                if ((totalCount + 1) > goalControl) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (totalCount < goalControl) {
            return false;
        } else if (totalCount == goalControl) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(canPack(1, 0, 4));
    }
}
```